# Attribute in the block in not print via mtext

Tags: c#, autocad

This is my code which select block as per user selection and print attrbutes in that block using mtext but mtext is not working here.And also i dnt want repeated attributes with same no.. Thanks in advance.

```
    [CommandMethod("NALATT")]
    public void ListAttributes()
    {
        Document acDoc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Editor ed = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor;
        Database db =HostApplicationServices.WorkingDatabase;
        Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction();

        // Start the transaction
        try
        {
            // Build a filter list so that only
            // block references are selected
            TypedValue[] filList = new TypedValue[1] {new TypedValue((int)DxfCode.Start, "INSERT")};
            SelectionFilter filter = new SelectionFilter(filList);

            PromptSelectionOptions opts = new PromptSelectionOptions();

            opts.MessageForAdding = "Select block references: ";

            PromptSelectionResult res = ed.GetSelection(opts, filter);

            // Do nothing if selection is unsuccessful

            if (res.Status != PromptStatus.OK)

                return;

            SelectionSet selSet = res.Value;

            ObjectId[] idArray = selSet.GetObjectIds();

            PromptPointResult ppr;

            PromptPointOptions ppo = new PromptPointOptions("");

            //get the coordinates from user
            ppo.Message = "\n Select the place for print output:";

            ppr = acDoc.Editor.GetPoint(ppo);

            Point3d ptstart = ppr.Value;

            ppo.UseBasePoint = true;

            ppo.BasePoint = ptstart;

            if (ppr.Status == PromptStatus.Cancel) return;

            double x = ptstart.X;

            double y = ptstart.Y;

            double z = 1;

            foreach (ObjectId blkId in idArray)

            {
                BlockReference blkRef =(BlockReference)tr.GetObject(blkId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                BlockTableRecord btr = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(blkRef.BlockTableRecord, OpenMode.ForWrite );

                ed.WriteMessage("\nBlock: " + btr.Name);

                btr.Dispose();

                AttributeCollection attCol = blkRef.AttributeCollection;

                foreach (ObjectId attId in attCol)
                {
```

//This part is not working properly

```
                    MText mtext = new MText();

                    //mtext.SetDatabaseDefaults();

                    mtext.Width = 2;

                    mtext.Location = new Point3d(x, y = y - 1, z);

                    AttributeReference attRef =
```

(AttributeReference)tr.GetObject(attId,OpenMode.ForRead);

```
                    string str =("\n" + attRef.TextString);

                    mtext.Contents = "\n" + str;

                    ed.WriteMessage(str);

                    btr.AppendEntity(mtext);

                    tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(mtext, true);
                }
            }
            tr.Commit();
        }
        catch (Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception ex)
        {
            ed.WriteMessage(("Exception: " + ex.Message));
        }
        finally
        {
            tr.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I want to print that text on my dwg file

Comment: What exactly is "not working properly"? Is `MText` causing a crash or is it not shown in the editor? You have to be a little more precise in order to get the help you want.

Comment: Mtext is not display

Comment: If u have a solution plz suggest me its too imp.for me

Comment: At first sight it looks like it should work.
Have you checked if your `mtext` variable contains any text from `attreff`at all? Maybe it's an empty string

Comment: actually its print mtext but location is different

Comment: Is there any problem if i develope command in autocad 2011 and try to run in autocad 2016? Because it gives me exception and references is also different so is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand exactly what you want to do but the following code "prints" the values of the attributes of the selected blocks in the current space.
I tried to be as closed as possible to the code you posted

```
    [CommandMethod("NALATT")]
    public void ListAttributes()
    {
        Document acDoc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Editor ed = acDoc.Editor;
        Database db = acDoc.Database;
        using (Transaction tr = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            // Start the transaction
            try
            {
                // Build a filter list so that only
                // block references with attributes are selected
                TypedValue[] filList = new TypedValue[2] { new TypedValue((int)DxfCode.Start, "INSERT"), new TypedValue((int)DxfCode.HasSubentities, 1) };
                SelectionFilter filter = new SelectionFilter(filList);
                PromptSelectionOptions opts = new PromptSelectionOptions();
                opts.MessageForAdding = "Select block references: ";
                PromptSelectionResult res = ed.GetSelection(opts, filter);
                // Do nothing if selection is unsuccessful
                if (res.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
                    return;
                SelectionSet selSet = res.Value;
                ObjectId[] idArray = selSet.GetObjectIds();

                PromptPointResult ppr;
                PromptPointOptions ppo = new PromptPointOptions("");
                ppo.Message = "\n Select the place for print output:";
                //get the coordinates from user
                ppr = ed.GetPoint(ppo);
                if (ppr.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
                    return;
                Point3d startPoint = ppr.Value.TransformBy(ed.CurrentUserCoordinateSystem);
                Vector3d disp = new Vector3d(0.0, -2.0 * db.Textsize, 0.0);

                //a HashSet to store printed strings to avoid duplicated values
                HashSet<string> attValues = new HashSet<string>();

                foreach (ObjectId blkId in idArray)
                {
                    BlockReference blkRef = (BlockReference)tr.GetObject(blkId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                    BlockTableRecord btr = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(blkRef.BlockTableRecord, OpenMode.ForWrite);
                    ed.WriteMessage("\nBlock: " + btr.Name);

                    // get the current space (where to print the attributes values)
                    var curSpace = (BlockTableRecord)tr.GetObject(db.CurrentSpaceId, OpenMode.ForWrite);

                    AttributeCollection attCol = blkRef.AttributeCollection;
                    foreach (ObjectId attId in attCol)
                    {
                        AttributeReference attRef = (AttributeReference)tr.GetObject(attId, OpenMode.ForRead);
                        string str = (attRef.TextString);
                        ed.WriteMessage("\n" + str);
                        if (attValues.Contains(str))
                            continue;

                        // add the mtext to current space
                        MText mtext = new MText();
                        mtext.Width = 2;
                        mtext.Location = startPoint;
                        mtext.Contents = str;
                        curSpace.AppendEntity(mtext);
                        tr.AddNewlyCreatedDBObject(mtext, true);
                        db.TransactionManager.QueueForGraphicsFlush();
                        // add the string to the HashSet
                        attValues.Add(str);
                        // move the insertion point
                        startPoint += disp;
                    }
                }
                tr.Commit();
            }
            catch (Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception ex)
            {
                ed.WriteMessage(("Exception: " + ex.Message));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have one dwg file its name is 534-W1A-R1.dwg i want to print only W1A-R1 using mtext on my dwg file